# Proof that $n$-th root of $n$-th partial convergent's denominator almost always tends to $e^{\frac{\pi^2}{12\ln{2}}}$

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, continued-fractions, constants

While reading Steven Finch's book *Mathematical constants* (I believe), I once came across and wrote down the following theorem: For [almost all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all) real numbers $x$, if $\frac{P_n}{Q_n}$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ [partial convergent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convergent.html) of the [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) of $x$, then:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Q_n^{\;\frac{1}{n}}=e^{\frac{\pi^2}{12\ln{2}}}\tag{*}$$

This seems like a fascinating result; presumably the $\ln{2}$ in the exponent comes from the same place as the base $2$ [logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) in the expressions for the [Gauss-Kuzmin distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Kuzmin_distribution) and [Khinchin's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khinchin's_constant), although I am not too familiar with the asymptotics of continued fractions. The factor of $\frac{\pi^2}{12}$ seems more unusual; does it perhaps come from $\zeta(2)$, e.g. something to do with the [fact](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410597/zeta-function-and-probability) that $\zeta(2)$ is related to the probability of two randomly chosen integers being coprime, or perhaps there is just some arcane way of transforming the LHS of $(*)$ to get $\zeta(2)$ involved? I am therefore curious for a general idea of the methods that would be used to prove this result, or even a sketch of such a proof (I no longer have access to the book, and I haven't been able to find a reference for this formula online by searching all the relevant words I can think of, so I'm not sure where to look).

Thus my question is: By what methods can $(*)$ be proved, and is there a simple elegant way of proving it?

Comment: Look up Lévy's constant.

Comment: @Gary It was there under my nose and I didn't find it. Looks like it was discovered by Khinchin, so presumably the proof uses similar techniques to that of Khinchin's constant (which I think involves ergodic theory, which I'm not especially familiar with). I half hoped there would be some sort of intuitive argument for this result, but I now am less hopeful. Thanks!

Comment: The page I linked to on Khinchin's constant even links to Levy's constant. I guess without realizing the RHS had a name I wouldn't have known that was where the answer lay.