# Can we showed the existence of $a_i,b_i$ such that $\zeta(3)(2C-1)=1+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{b_i}(\zeta(a_i)-1)$

Tags: improper-integrals, riemann-zeta, constants

It's a follow up of [Show that : $\frac{1}{\zeta(3)}<2C-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4693000/show-that-frac1-zeta32c-1)

I showed by hand that :

$$\frac{1}{\zeta(3)}<2C-1$$

Using classical continued fraction .

Now I want to go further and a conjecture :

Conjecture:

$\exists a_i,a_i>3 \exists b_i, b_i \in [1,2]$ all integers then it seems we have :

$$\zeta(3)(2C-1)=1+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{b_i}(\zeta(a_i)-1)$$

For example we have :

$$0<\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac{1}{n^{15}}-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}}{e^{x}-1}dx\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{\cosh\left(x\right)}-xe^{-x}\right)dx-\sum_{n=2}^{100}\frac{1}{n^{19}}-\sum_{n=2}^{100}\frac{1}{n^{24}}+\sum_{n=2}^{100}\frac{1}{n^{27}}+\sum_{n=2}^{100}\frac{1}{n^{33}}<7*10^{-11}$$

Question :

As I have no idea to show or evaluate the difficulty of the problem :

How to show the existence of $a_i,b_i$ ?

Any helps is awesomely appreciated .