# A series equal to $\pi G-\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

I find a reference see [Chavan and Vignat - Evaluation of multivariate integrals based on a duality identity for the Stieltjes transform](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.11771) we have :

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln\left(\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-\ln\left(\cos\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\right)}{\cos\left(x\right)-\cos\left(z\right)}dxdz=\pi G-\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3).$$

Then we can use $a,x\in[0,\pi/2)$ :

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{\ln\left(\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-\ln\left(\cos\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\right)}{\cos\left(x\right)-\cos\left(z\right)},g\left(x\right)=\frac{e^{\frac{x}{4}}}{2}+\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{4}}}{2}-1+f\left(0\right),h\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right).$$

Then we have :
\begin{gather*}
f(x)= g\left(x\right)+\frac{h''\left(0\right)}{2}x^{2}+\frac{h''''\left(0\right)}{4!}x^{4}+\dotsb \\
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(g\left(x\right)+\frac{h''\left(0\right)}{2}x^{2}+\frac{h''''\left(0\right)}{4!}x^{4}+\frac{h''''''\left(0\right)}{6!}x^{6}+\dotsb\right)dxdz.\tag{I}\label{I}
\end{gather*}

My motivation is related to [Show that : $\frac{1}{\zeta(3)}<2C-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4693000/show-that-frac1-zeta32c-1) . In fact I tried to find a sufficently accurate series to evaluate the product in question .

Question :

How does \eqref{I} look in terms of values or how to get the series equal to the integral in terms of known value instead of valued function  ?