# Closed form for $\int_{0}^{1}((\frac{2\arctan(x)}{x}-\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}})((\frac{6}{5}-x^{\frac{4}{5}}-\frac{1}{10})^{\frac{6}{5}}))^{1/2}dx=?$

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, power-series, radicals, closed-form

It's a kind of follow up of [Show that : $\frac{1}{\zeta(3)}<2C-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4693000/show-that-frac1-zeta32c-1):

Does the following integral have a closed form or a nice representation (series,equation,integral...)?:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left(\frac{2\arctan\left(x\right)}{x}-\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\left(\left(\frac{6}{5}-x^{\frac{4}{5}}-\frac{1}{10}\right)^{\frac{6}{5}}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx=I=?$$

### Background :

This integral comes from an attempt to use Cauchy-Schwarz to evaluate the product in the linked question above

### Motivation :

It would be benefic to understand the problem with Catalan's constant and $\zeta(3)$ in evaluating this integral above knowing we can use Callebaut's inequality (in continuous form) to show the inequality .

### Attempt :

$I$ have some similarities with the integral :

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left(\frac{2\tanh\left(x\right)}{x}-\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\left(\left(\frac{6}{5}-x^{\frac{4}{5}}-\frac{1}{10}\right)^{\frac{6}{5}}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx$$

So using the series of hyperbolic tangent we have :

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left(\frac{2\left(x-\frac{x^{3}}{3}+\frac{2}{15}x^{5}\right)}{x}-\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\left(\left(\frac{6}{5}-x^{\frac{4}{5}}-\frac{1}{10}\right)^{\frac{6}{5}}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx\simeq I$$

As you can see It's already a monster as integral and I cannot find an issue .

### Question :

What is $I$ ? And if there is no closed form what would be interesting to say about it ?

Comment: Perhaps express it as a double Integral and use polar coordinate...?